# fetch country name and region from the url [Google](http://ipinfo.io)

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have url which returns a json string results are:

```
{
    "ip": "202.141.243.124",
    "hostname": "No Hostname",
    "city": "Peshawar",
    "region": "Khyber Pakhtunkhwa",
    "country": "PK",
    "loc": "34.0080,71.5785",
    "org": "AS9260 Multinet Pakistan Pvt. Ltd.",
    "postal": "24650"
}
```

I want country name and state from it. How can i get it?
Help me guys, help me through code please.

Comment: You can use Json.net, http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to install `Json.Net` from NuGet

```
PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

Then try this...

```
void Main()
{
    const string testJson = "{ \"ip\": \"202.141.243.124\", \"hostname\": \"No Hostname\", \"city\": \"Peshawar\", \"region" +
    "\": \"Khyber Pakhtunkhwa\", \"country\": \"PK\", \"loc\": \"34.0080,71.5785\", \"org\": \"AS92" +
    "60 Multinet Pakistan Pvt. Ltd.\", \"postal\": \"24650\" }";
    
    IpInfo ipInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IpInfo>(testJson);
    
}


public class IpInfo
{

    [JsonProperty("ip")]
    public string Ip { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("hostname")]
    public string Hostname { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("city")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("region")]
    public string Region { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("country")]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("loc")]
    public string Loc { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("org")]
    public string Org { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("postal")]
    public string Postal { get; set; }
}
```

Result

[image: Result]

---

## Tips

You can generate the classes required to replicate the structure of whichever JSON document you're trying to deserialize, in this example, it was the `IpInfo` class that was generated.

You can do this in one of two ways, one is using [Json2CSharp](http://json2csharp.com/) and pasting your JSON data there to generate the class, alternatively you can download [Xamasoft JSON Class Generator](http://www.xamasoft.com/json-class-generator/) (the one that I prefer and used in answering your question).

Comment: Thank you for the answer but ip wont remain same it will change according to the visitor visiting our site so will this code be fine ? for that

Comment: The IP doesn't need to remain the same, but the structure of that JSON document does need to be consistent, so in short, yes, it will be fine :)

Comment: ok Thanks ill apply this :)

Comment: but one thing how can i do it without making class ?? i want it dynamically

Comment: `dynamic ipInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(testJson);` Then to access the IP address... `Console.WriteLine(ipInfo.ip);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Json.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) to deserialise to a `JObject` and then get the `region` and `country` values.